# check whether a url is part of angular application

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a web app that was partly migrated from PHP and angular-js to angular(currently v13)
after a successful login, there's a redirection to other pages.
since my login page is angular-based, I'd like to use angular routing to redirect to pages that are angular-based and are working under the `router-outlet`. And redirect using `window.location` for old pages (e.g PHP).

The url to redirect to is dynamic.
Is there a way that I can determine if the url is part of the angular application and can be navigated to using the router?

Comment: If all your routing is consistently done with Angular directives or API, then any page matching your routes will load the corresponding component into `router-outlet`. Now if you have a fallback 404 page for all remaining URLs, then in this 404 page you can redirect to your old pages utilizing `window.location`.

Comment: @Benny so you suggest having an empty 404 component that will just redirect using `window.location`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe @Anton's answer below is more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use router events for that.
Do this code in a service or your root navigation component:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationError),
      takeUntil(this.destroy),
    ).subscribe(.. here you should redirect with window.location);
  }
```

Also if you needn't error in the console, just provide custom error handler in providers:

```
providers: [{
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: CustomErrorHandler,
}],
```

And one last moment: you have to remove `'**'` path parsing from your root routes in `RouterModule`.

Comment: looks good, I'll try it :) what is `this.destroy`?

Comment: Just the Subject, emits value and completes in `OnDestroy` hook. Recommend to use in any subscriptions :)

Comment: Marineko I've used your solution and it's working well, the thing is that now if a client use the url bar to change the url to an angular component and have a mistake I can't redirect him to a not found page and he just gets redirected infinitely. is there any way to avoid this scenario?

Comment: @Daniel you have to listen browser api for that. Make `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` with function to check.